# How to find Different Resources in any given endpoint

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

For Suppose in soap web services.
if we input WSDL then we can fetch how many operations are there in that particular WSDL.
Similar way Do we have anything in Rest Web Services To fetch Different Resources in any given Endpoint.?

Answer (score 0):

REST works on the *convention over configuration* concept. That is, REST is schema-less by design.

Since resource URIs are predictable and REST encourages using HTTP verbs to represent different actions against resources, there's no need to have a WSDL counterpart.

BTW, you can always provide [an API documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages).

Comment: Does RAML SWAGGER serve the Purpose? to Parse the Rest Information

Comment: @KishoreBabu I think so. I've never used it yet, but I've a friend who has recommended me Swagger ;)

Comment: @KishoreBabu Anyway, follow the link in my answer. For simple cases it should work well

Comment: I didn't get any link:)

Comment: @KishoreBabu See the last sentence. "an API documentation" is a link... :P

Comment: @KishoreBabu No problem ;)